# jqGrid find and replace

Tags: jqgrid

Is there a find replace function within jqGrid?

I'm struggling with implementing my own;

I have an array of data that I bind my grid to like this;

```
data: GRID.GridData,
```

On find and replace I go through that array and make the changes which works great.  However, when I edit a cell within the grid, the change is not posted to my array.  Instead it's in another array that jqGrid uses for some reason.  So now SLAPPY is in the cell but not in Grid.GridData and so when I come to save the data back to the server, the cell edits the user made are not reflected.

So, no problem, I then used code like this;

```
var rowData = $('#fieldJobAddressListGrid').jqGrid('getRowData', "11332601");
rowData.State = "SLAPPY";
$('#fieldJobAddressListGrid').jqGrid('setRowData', "11332601", rowData);
```

But this sets the column value to be SLAPPY and then it immediately reloads using GRID.GridData and destroys the value in the cell.

How can I allow the user to edit a cell, and programmatically alter the value in a cell and have that all flow back to GRID.GridData?

The grid is setup like this for the data;

```
grid.jqGrid({
    datatype: "local",
    data: GRID.GridData,
```

I have tried adding `loadonce` to no effect.

Comment: which version of jqGrid you use? Editing of the grid having `datatype: "local"` by `setRowData` or `setCell` *updates* internal `data` array of items. You wrote "it immediately reloads using GRID.GridData and destroys the value in the cell". Who makes reloading of the grid? Do you makes this explicitly? Can you provide a demo which reproduces the problem?

Comment: I am using 4.6.0.  Who reloads the grid?  I don't know.  I change data and the grid reloads on its own.  I am certainly not instructing it to reload.  Sorry, no I can't provide a working example. I need to get on with other things.

Comment: Sorry, but jqGrid don't reloads the grid inside of `setRowData`. You can examine the code it [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L3182-L3230) to verify this. You can use `jquery.jqGrid.src.js` instead of `jquery.jqGrid.min.js` and set breakpoint on [the first line](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/js/grid.base.js#L2759) to locale the place of *your code* which triggers directly or indirectly `reloadGrid`.

Comment: OK, I understand your comment but it's contrary to what I am seeing here.  I'll take a closer look at the source like you have suggested.  thanks again.